# Integrate jQuery function into html page

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Just edited:**
I have a weird problem with a jQuery function. My function works well on a small jsFiddle on every browser `example:` http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/72/
but if I want to integrate that function in my html page it is not working on Google Chrome and IE8. On Firefox works great.

Comment: please add your function code here for proper solution

Comment: Correction: please post a short self contained example of your problem here for a proper solution.

Comment: @burebistaruler: if those links were to become stale, this question would too... consider providing everything relevant to the question in the body of your question.

Comment: or you can check jsFiddle example

Comment: Edit the post and put the code into there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, your click is not highlighting the correct rows because the tables on your live site had a different layout in your example.

In the example your rows maps 1:1.

On the live site your second table has two extra rows:

```
<tr class="navigation"> ...
<tr class="headers"> ...
```

which obviously breaks your order-based matching.

Your hover is broken because, again, your example is different from your live site.

In your example you have:

```
$(".table").each(function(){          
    $("tr:eq("+row+")",this).addClass("hoverx");
});
```

but on the live site in `focus.js` you have:

```
$("table.grid tbody tr").each(function(){          
      $("tr:eq("+row+")",this).addClass("hoverx");
});
```

Note how you are looping over the rows in the second case.

**Edit**

I think using `tbody` to group the interactive rows is a nice solution to your problem of having additional rows in the second table. You could also simplify your javascript a bit as a result:

[Example with second table having more rows](http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/11/)

Per requested here's what a solution using `not` would look like. Note you pretty much have to filter it out everywhere you select a `tr`.

[Example using `not` and making the minimum amount of changes to the original code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/12/)

Comment: hmmmmm yes, you have right. Is possible to ignore that tr (navigation,headers)? Or maybe to use that function for all I have into <tbody> </tbody>

Comment: @burebistaruler you could exclude them in your selector: `$('tr').not('.navigation, .headers').eq(row)`. Or you could format your HTML differently as you say, and put all the selectable row into their own `tbody`.

Comment: @burebistaruler I have provided an example using `not` in my edit. Unfortunately I do not have time now to clean up that example, but hopefully the idea behind it is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Henry, and yes your ideea was very helpful.